# Using C defines to simplify constant definitions?

Tags: c

I have the following defines:

```c
#define M(x) ( ((uint64_t) 1) << (x) )
```

```c
#define Mx  M(0)
#define My  M(1)
#define Mz  M(2)
```

Quite often I need to rearrange the order of Mx, My, Mz, for example:

```c
#define My  M(0)
#define Mz  M(1)
#define Mx  M(2)
```

How would I make this more generic in a sense of not having to correct `M(0/1/2)` every time, but just shuffle the lines?

```c
#define POS ... 

#define My  M(POS)
#define Mz  M(POS)
#define Mx  M(POS)
```

Comment: how are `Mx/My/Mz` used? There might be better alternatives than redefining `POS`

Comment: @tstanisl Added a line where you can see what `M(x)` in fact is evaluated to.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an extra macro in between that will select an appropriate argument from the permutation. The permutation would be a macro itself that can be undefined and redefined.

```
#define NTH0(a0,a1,a2) a0
#define NTH1(a0,a1,a2) a1
#define NTH2(a0,a1,a2) a2
#define NTH(n, perm) NTH ## n (perm)

#define Mx  M(NTH(0, PERM))
#define My  M(NTH(1, PERM))
#define Mz  M(NTH(2, PERM))

#define PERM 1,2,3

Mx
My
Mz

#undef PERM
#define PERM 3,2,1

Mx
My
Mz
```

When compiled with `gcc -E` it expands to:

```
M(1)
M(2)
M(3)




M(3)
M(2)
M(1)
```

Comment: This will not work in my case, unfortunatelly. What I need is really a visualy clear defines, one below the other in separate rows. `PERM 3, 2, 1` would be too criptic, especially in cases where there are much more than 3 elements (usually about 15).

Comment: @Danijel, there is not much problem with expanding this to support 15 arguments. Note that `PERM` could expand to other macro like `PERM_IDENTITY` or `PERM_REVERSED`, that expands to `0,1,2` and `2,1,0` respectively. This should be less cryptic

Answer (score 1):

The best solution might be to solve this with version control or `#ifdef` switches rather than function-like macros. Or perhaps generate the C source through a script.

Otherwise, the standard pre-processor way to list stuff while avoiding code repetition is "X macros", where you only need to change the values in a single place (called `M_LIST` in this example):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define M_LIST(X) \
  X(x,0)          \
  X(y,1)          \
  X(z,2)          \

#define M_enum(symbol,val) M##symbol##_bit = val,
enum { M_LIST(M_enum) };

#define M(symbol) ( 1ull << (M##symbol##_bit) )

int main (void)
{
  printf("%.16"PRIx64"\n", M(x));
  printf("%.16"PRIx64"\n", M(y));
  printf("%.16"PRIx64"\n", M(z));
}
```

Here a temporary enum is created, which will expand to:
`enum { Mx_bit = 0, My_bit = 1, Mz_bit = 2, }`. These constants aren't used directly by your program, but only through the macro `M`.

Comment: Interesting usage of enum. How would you handle changing the permutation, by redefining `M` to use other `enum`?

Comment: @tstanisl You could in theory use an extra parameter to `M` such as `#define M(symbol,type) ( 1ull << (M##symbol##_##type) )`. Where each `type` corresponds to an enum, which corresponds to an X macro list. If that's good design or not, well that's another story.